# I am trying to migrate from Lubuntu 19.0.4 disco to 20.0.4 focal via 19.10 but keep hitting wall, xvfb & python3-psutil dependencies?

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04, migration

Here is what I get
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
chrome-remote-desktop : Depends: xvfb but it is not installed
Depends: python3-psutil but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Note version 19.04 has reached it's end of life. It is 19.04, meaning the the year of 2019 and the month of April, not 19.0.4.

Comment: You should also note that 19.10 has also already reached EOL.  You might not be able to upgrade and might need to install 20.04 cleanly. If you don't want to upgrade to a new release every 6 months, I suggest sticking with an LTS release

Comment: You need to ensure your system is fully-upgraded before *release-upgrade* (ie. 19.04 needed to be fully-upgraded) before moving to 19.10.  You haven't mentioned which commands you used, however in-built upgrade tools will no longer upgrade you to 19.10 as it's now EOL so you've missed that upgrade path. Skipping 19.10 isn't supported except via re-install.  You didn't provide the command & full error messages, however I get the feeling you're upgrading by treating it as a non-Ubuntu system thus your python issue (as often occurs as Ubuntu uses python more heavily than Debian).

Comment: The Lubuntu page on upgrading is available at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/D/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and see if that works